# Access nested items in python JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, dataset

I'm loading a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{"questions": 
     [{"question_id": 0, "image_filename": "CLEVR_val_009641.png", "question": "Are there any tiny green things made of the same material as the small brown sphere?"}, 
     {"question_id": 1, "image_filename": "CLEVR_val_010849.png", "question": "Are there any purple metal things of the same size as the green shiny object?"}, 
     {"question_id": 2, "image_filename": "CLEVR_val_004213.png", "question": "Is there a big thing of the same color as the big metal ball?"}, 
     {"question_id": 3, "image_filename": "CLEVR_val_012597.png", "question": "There is a big metallic thing to the right of the blue rubber object; are there any small cyan rubber blocks that are to the right of it?"}, 
     {"question_id": 4, "image_filename": "CLEVR_val_006304.png", "question": "Is there any other thing that has the same material as the small brown object?"}
     ]
}
```

I'm using `json.loads()` to load the file.

So far, using:

```
train_data_jsonload = json.load(f)
train_data = train_data_jsonload.get("questions")
```

I've been able to load the whole "dataset".

I would like to load only the `question` key in my json file (so all the questions, without `question_id` and `image_filename`)

I tried to use `train_data.get("question")` but i get the error `list object has no attribute 'get'`

I also tried to use what has been suggested suggested here: [Nested dictionary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary) without any success

So, back to my question, how do i select only the `question` fields?

Comment: What's unclear from the error message? You have a *list* of dictionaries. If you want the question key's value for each dictionary in that list, you'll have to iterate over it.

Comment: Your comment solved my problem. I was confused since i expected to get a dictionary from my .get() and the error reported list. Pretty stupid mistake, i solve the problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try_this:

```
train_data_jsonload = json.load(f)
for questions_info in train_data_jsonload["questions"]:
   question  = question_info["question"]
   #Do required stuff here if needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of questions as a an output, just use list comprehension:

`text_questions = [item["question"] for item in train_data_jsonload.get("questions")]`

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found the solution:

```
for element in train_data:
    print(element.get("question"))
```

Will print every single question.